# Which is a better to call certain numpy methods?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Both numpy.shape(a) and a.shape seem to provide the shape of the array a. Which is the better method and why?

Comment: Methods/attributes and functions are two different things. `numpy.shape(a)` and `a.shape` are two different things that happen to produce the same result, not two alternative syntaxes for the same thing.  In the former, `a` just has to be array-*like*; in the latter, it has to be an instance of a type that has a `shape` attribute. Compare `numpy.shape([1,2,3])` and `[1,2,3].shape`, for example.

Comment: `resize` and `reshape` are two different operations.

Comment: "i found that a.resize does not work, but a.reshape works". Please clarify or consider removing this part. Both functions "work", so you would have to provide a concrete example of what you mean to get an explanation. Most likely, that would be better left as a separate question, posted after you check google to make sure that it's not already answered elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I realised that a.resize is not working due to "ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced by another array in this way. Use the np.resize function or refcheck=False", which seems to be a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

For a numpy array, there is almost no perceptible difference between `np.shape` and `np.ndarray.shape`. There may be some minimal differences in timing because of overhead, but the functionality is the same.

Numpy functions accept not only arrays, but also array-likes. So you can do something like

```
np.shape([1, 2, 3])
```

But NOT

```
[1, 2, 3].shape
```

Comment: Jinx. (I finished my comment before your answer appeared.)

Comment: @chepner. Wow. Nice choice of sample array-like :)